# How to Link the index of two listbox in VB6

Tags: listbox, vb6

Is there a way to link the index of two listboxes? For example, I have 2 listboxes and I want to delete a value in the 1st listbox and have the second listbox delete the same index as the 1st listbox.

Comment: It would help if you showed us some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Not much research or effort shown here. If you're already using RemoveItem on the first listbox, just use it on the second listbox - same syntax and parameter values - just different control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have something like below...

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim xRemove As Integer

xRemove = List1.ListIndex

List2.ListIndex = xRemove

List2.RemoveItem xRemove
End Sub
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the idea :)